# numpy read TSV file as ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to read a TSV into numpy array. 
Is there are generic way to read data from file and convert it into numpy array of floats. (There are few missing values as well)

The file looks like

```
Variable_1 ..... Variable_100
 0.001     ..... 0.25
  ...            ...
 1.65      ..... 1.32
```

I tried

```
def converter(x): 
   return float(x)

data = np.genfromtxt(fname="file.tsv", delimiter="\t", skip_header=0, names=True, converters={"Variable_" + str(n):converter for n in range(1554)})
```

However after reading the file shape is 1D array instead of ndarray of rows=200 cols=100

```
data.shape
(200,)
```

Comment: What does `file.tsv` look like?

Comment: what's the `dtype`?

Comment: Are there delimiters between missing values?

Comment: @hpaulj no missing values are blanks. 0.1235<tab><tab>0.3654. All columns are Float except last one which is integer

Comment: Can you show us what the incorrect output `data` looks like?

Comment: What's the dtype? Did it load a structured array?  If you don't want that try a simpler load, without names and converters, skipping the header line?

Comment: What's the purpose of the converters parameter?  It can handle floats without that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing what the `file.tsv` file looks like, you could use pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method to read the `.tsv` file into memory as a dataframe, then access the `.values` of the dataframe, which will return the array of interest:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make a dummy .tsv file, save it to disk
dummy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(200,100)))
save_path = "foo.tsv"
dummy.to_csv(save_path, index=False, sep="\t")

df = pd.read_csv(save_path, sep="\t")   # read dummy .tsv file into memory

a = df.values  # access the numpy array containing values
```

Now you'll have an array of shape (200,100):

```
print a.shape
print a

(200, 100)
[[4 1 8 ... 2 7 0]
 [0 1 9 ... 7 1 3]
 [7 6 6 ... 9 0 2]
 ...
 [1 5 1 ... 1 8 7]
 [7 4 6 ... 9 6 0]
 [2 0 1 ... 3 2 9]]
```

You've mentioned having missing values within the original `.tsv` file.  To accommodate this, you can leverage pandas's [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) method to fill values in either a particular column, or throughout the entire dataframe:

```
df.col_1.fillna(1, inplace=True)  # fill missing values with 1 in a single col

df.fillna(1, inplace=True) # fill all missing values with 1 in entire frame
```

### UPDATE

The OP requests that *only* numpy's `genfromtxt()` be used.  In this case, the following is required:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(fname="foo.tsv", delimiter="\t", skip_header=1, filling_values=1)  # change filling_values as req'd to fill in missing values

print data.shape  # (200,100)
```

Comment: Your suggestion works. This is what I have already done. I know it sounds odd, but for the purpose of this task I am not allowed to use pandas.. (Sorry I forgot to mention it in the question)